# Using HTML Table as a Timesheet Layout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, user-interface

I am trying to create a time sheet in a table and using colspan attribute to achieve the start and end time highlight. The problem is that column width is getting increased.

```
switch(time){
case "11 AM":
{
 var cell=1;
 $("#"+MemberID)[0].cells[cell].colSpan=hours;
 $("#"+MemberID)[0].cells[cell].innerHTML+="<p>"+res[i].JobID+"</p>";
 $("#"+MemberID)[0].cells[cell].style.backgroundColor = color;
 break;
}
}
```

The above code identifies the start time and add the time difference as colspan so that the column could extend to the end time. But this logic affects the width, Is there a better approach to achieve this. I am new to design.

[image: NL]

Comment: Show some code. We cannot help you without it.

Comment: Added the code for the reference.

Comment: Still not enough, but it seems you're just modyfying the cell colspan, so the sum of colspans is bigger than your available column count.

Comment: What do you mean, affects the width? Your code explicitly edits the colspan, which makes it wider. You could instead try to just leave the widths as standard cells, but then iterate through the cells and edit the necessary ones to have a different background colour

Comment: Yes.. Is there any alternative approach I could try to achieve this same without using colspan @Luke.

Comment: You can insert table cells on the fly and make sure that you have correct number of columns filled.

Comment: @Magiczne Thank you .. I will try that..